# How do I make a huge table of data load faster on a webpage assuming DB is already indexed?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Say I have a webmail service and I have a table with fields - username, IP, location, login_time. Let us say my service is hugely popular with 100s of users logging in every minute. At end of the day, if I want to display this table for today's list of users, there are say half a million rows. Now even after indexing DB table, it's taking a huge amount of time to load this page. How do I make it faster (or give a feel of speedy load) ? May be I can do pagination and load say 50 rows at a time as users shift pages. What if I do not have that option ?

Comment: Replace line 5 and 11 with line 546, delete line 4... Show code first!

Comment: No the database is your problem. The browser is it: showing that many lines in a html table is slow, sending the data to the browser is slow.

Comment: First of all you need to think how much is the ram on your machine to handle that query. And it is not good idea to load 1/2 millions row in one go . You might need to increase the query execution time as well.S o think all those factors. and if possible try to do the pagination.

Comment: Half a million rows each of probably 100 bytes min is 50mb of data just to download. And that is assuming virtually no formatting and a basic HTML table. That is likely to be slow even if the data is retrieved from the database instantly

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to use a Jquery "Load more" plugin and get only a restricted amount of data at once... Users can click "Load more" button and see the whole table if they want.

Answer (score 1):

Use backend pagination, as you said.

Imagine that you have an excel file containing that many rows - how fast do you think it will open? And, unlike your browser, excel is a specialized software to work with rows of data.

Put it in another perspective - is it helpful in some way for the user to see .5 millions rows at once? I doubt they do. The user can get exactly the same functionality from your software if you offer him a paged results list, with a search form.

Answer (score 0):

I think table Partitioning based on the **login_time** column is the solution.Partitioning lets you to store parts of your table in their own logical space. Your query will only have to look at a subset of the data to get a result, and not the whole table making the query multiple times faster depending on the number of rows. More about partitioning in the below link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Once you have partitioned your table, you can use a pagination mechanism since showing all 0.5 million rows to the user would not serve any purpose.